# Typical time scales for spin dynamics and lattice vibrations in magnetic solids

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

In a paper from the 1990s ([1]) on magnetovolume effects in ferromagnets, it is written that

*in most real situations, the moment (or spin) autocorrelation time is much larger than the period for typical atomic vibrations. That is, in the average time between successive spin fluctuations on a given moment, the moment-bearing atom experiences many (10^2-10^5) atomic vibrations cycles.*

They only give two references in this connection. One is [2], which seems to be very specific for solitons in 1D Ising chains (and whose reading is proving quite challenging to me), the other is the beautiful book on Solid State theory by Ashcroft and Mermin [3], where I cannot find this piece of information.

Is there a general consensus on whether spin time scales are longer than those of vibrational degrees of freedom/phonons in solids? Is there any theoretical argument supporting that claim? Is it a well established experimental fact?

[1] B. Grossmann and D. G. Rancourt, Phys. Rev. B, 54, 12 294 (1996)

[2] D. G. Rancourt, Solid State Commun, 58, 433 (1986)

[3] N. W. Ashcroft and N. D. Mermin, *Solid State Physics* (Saunders College, Philadelphia, 1976)